# Javascript how to pass clicked target to callback function

Tags: javascript

I am refactoring my code into a class. Using `this` has brought up a couple of issues which I have mostly solved. However I still have one issue regarding using arrow function to pass the global `this` into a callback function so I can access the variables. But I need to pass a reference of the clicked event too.

I have tried:

```
$(document).on("click", ".card:not(.flip)" , ({currentTarget}) => this.flipCard());
```

and

```
$(document).on("click", ".card:not(.flip)" , (event) => this.flipCard());
```

But I get undefined in the `flipCard()` method

```
flipCard () {

    if (this.lockDeck) return;
    
    $(event.currentTarget).addClass('flip');

    if (this === this.firstCard) return;
    if (!this.hasFlippedCard) {
        this.hasFlippedCard = true;
        this.firstCard = event.currentTarget;

        return;
    } 
    
    this.secondCard = event.currentTarget;
    this.checkForMatch();
}
```

I have also tried to pass the `event` in as an argument.

```
$(document).on("click", ".card:not(.flip)" , (event) => this.flipCard(event));
```

and

```
flipCard (event) {
```

Comment: where the error happens ? in the `flipCard` method?

Comment: Yes, when I call `event.currentTarget`

Comment: The `flipCard` isn't currently expecting any arguments. `flipCard (event) {}` and pass the event

Comment: you have to pass the event to the flipCard method as an argument `this.flipCard(event)`

Comment: sorry, should have mention I have tried that too. I get the error `game.js:128 Uncaught ReferenceError: currentTarget is not defined`

Comment: @KeithPower you'd get that type of error when you try to use `currentTarget` as a variable somewhere within your code and it isn't defined. All of the code inside of `flipCard()` tries to access it as a property (and not as a stand-alone variable), so I'm not too sure that the error stems from the code you're showing (what is on line 128)

Comment: when I `console.log(event)` in `flipcard(event)` method I get `S.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", target: div.card-back.card-face, currentTarget: div.card, isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, …}` It should be accessible?

Comment: @KeithPower yes, you should be able to use `event.currentTarget` inside of flipCard if that what you're seeing. If not, are you getting any errors?

Comment: ah ok, my bad. I never changed the `currentTarget` back to `event. currentTarget` The error is now gone. Thanks